# xarray and 5 year averages from monthly or yearly avarges

Tags: time-series, average, mean, python-xarray

I need to calculate 5 year averaged data (not rolling average, but a calendar year one) from monthly mean or yearly mean time series data.
After searching xarray documentation I cannot see a simple way to do it.
Does anyone have a method for doing this type of averages?

thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to compute a 5 year average is to pass a custom frequency to [`resample()`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.resample.html), e.g.,

```
In [24]: ds = xr.Dataset({'x': ('time', np.arange(1000))},
    ...:                 {'time': pd.date_range('2000-01', freq='1MS', periods=1000)})

In [28]: ds.resample('5AS', dim='time')
Out[28]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 17)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2005-01-01 2010-01-01 ...
Data variables:
    x        (time) float64 29.5 89.5 149.5 209.5 269.5 329.5 389.5 449.5 ...
```

Here "AS" indicates "annual, start".

Comment: @user3207603: If you are concerned about proper weighting of the monthly means, this example may be of use to you: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/examples/monthly-means.html

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I will try the 5AS option.